# Flash SecureSocket and RSA private key

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ssl, private-key

I am trying to communicate to a server through SSL. The PEM client file is consisted of a certificate and an rsa private key.

I managed to convert both the certificate and key to binary DER. I load the DER certificate to SecureSocket succesfully (with function  ***addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate***) but when I try to connect to the server I get a "principal mismatch" error. If I try to use the aforementioned function to load the DER key, I get a "wrong parameter" error.

I suppose the "principal mismatch" is because I haven't loaded the private key. But I see no function to load an RSA key to SecureSocket. Is there any solution to this? Do I need to communicate to the server with only a certificate but remove the key from the equation?

**EDIT :**

Code :

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.net.SecureSocket;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class TestSSL2 extends Sprite {

        private var mSocket:SecureSocket = new SecureSocket();

        private var certFile:String = "ca.der";
        private var keyFile:String = "key.der";

        private var cert:ByteArray;
        private var key:ByteArray;

        public function TestSSL2() {
            trace("SecureSocket.isSupported",SecureSocket.isSupported);

            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, certLoaded, false, 0, true);
            urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
            urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(certFile));
        }
        private function certLoaded(e:Event):void {
            cert = (e.target as URLLoader).data;
            trace("certificate",cert.length);
            mSocket.addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate(cert, true);

            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, keyLoaded, false, 0, true);
            urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
            urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(keyFile));
        }
        private function keyLoaded(e:Event):void {
            key = (e.target as URLLoader).data;
            trace("key",key.length);
            mSocket.addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate(key, true);

            mSocket.connect("127.0.0.1", 3000);
            mSocket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, socketConnected);
            mSocket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
            mSocket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketData );
        }

        private function onError(error:IOErrorEvent):void {
            trace("ERROR!",error.text,":",mSocket.serverCertificateStatus);
        }

        private function socketConnected(e:Event):void {
            trace("Connected", e);
        }

        private function socketData(e:*):void {
            var data:String;
            data = mSocket.readUTFBytes(mSocket.bytesAvailable);
            trace(data);
        }
    }

}
```

Result :

```
SecureSocket.isSupported true
certificate 497
key 607
ArgumentError: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid.
    at flash.net::SecureSocket/addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate()
    at TestSSL2/keyLoaded()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

If I comment the line :

`//mSocket.addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate(key, true);`

I get :

```
SecureSocket.isSupported true
certificate 497
key 607
ERROR! Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: 127.0.0.1 : principalMismatch
```

Comment: Certs are loaded and validated when you do socket.connect? Other than that I can not help as you did not post code nor specific error codes.

Comment: Added, but can't really see how it could help :-( Allow me to add that the local server works fine with a local C++ client that reads the certificate and key from a pem file.

Comment: Are you launching the SWF locally or tested deployed to the web?

Comment: Maybe you should try to put "cert" and "key" cursor position to 0 (cert.position = 0)

Comment: That didn't work. It shouldn't, since the position is 0 by default after creating a ByteArray. Also, cert loads fine, it's the key that won't load. Maybe that's expected since a key in not a certificate. But SecureSocket doesn't boast a method to load a key. So what's the deal with that?

Comment: What host name was used when the certificate was created?  It is possible that the `principalMismatch` is that you are connecting via an IP address and not via the exact same host name used to create the certificate.  I know that browsers require the host name to exactly match the `CN=` name that is in the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly:

The "principal mismatch" indicates that the common name of the certificate on the secured server does not match the DNS name that you are connecting to.

Considering that you are making a connect to localhost (127.0.0.1) there will most certainly be a mismatch. Flash sockets are particularly strict when it comes to making secure connections and there is no mechanism to override security features unlike other runtimes (e.g. .NET and Java). The following must be true:

1. The certificate common name mush match the DNS name (there is a relaxation here for 'star' certs i.e. a cert for `*.bob.com` is considered valid for `mr.bob.com`)
2. The certificate must be valid in terms of expiry and trust chain

Secondly:

You seem to have some misconception on how certificates work. You do not need to add any certificates using the `addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate()` method if the server certificate is issued by a trusted root authority i.e. the certificate that signed the server certificate is in the local trust store of the target device.

To illustrate:

- I have a certificate for `this.is.awesome.com` installed on my server and a DNS entry that resolves `this.is.awesome.com` to my server's IP Address
- This certificate is issued by the Entrust L1C certificate authority.
- The L1C certificate is in turn issued by the Entrust 2048 root authority.

On my PC I have the Entrust 2048 Root authority installed in my Trusted Root certificate store.
However I do not have the L1C certificate installed. When I attempt to connect to `this.is.awesome.com` the connection will fail as the server certificate cannot be validated against the L1C authority.

If I add the DER encoded L1C certificate using `addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate()` then the connection will succeed. The server certificate will be validated against the L1C certificate which will in turn be validated against the 2048 Root certificate which is a trusted root.

To summarize:

Your connection issues seem to stem from your attempt to connect to localhost.
Try adding an entry to your HOSTS file that maps the name on your certificate to 127.0.0.1 and then connecting to that name. If that fails check the issuer chain on your certificate and add the chain of issuers by calling `addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate()` once for each issuing certificate in the chain. The final or root certificate should be marked as such by passing `true` as the second parameter to `addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate()`